# What am I #one hundred five

Tags: word

You can find me 3 times in the phrase:

> "When I awesomely win, I feel like a sexy rider"

What am I?

Slight Hint

> Most of the answers have been more literal than the intended one.

Hint

> Of the 3 times, 2 refer to product brands

Hint 2 after a year

> One of the aforementioned brands is British, a very rare occasion in its industry.

Answer (score 11):

You are a:

> Jot.

Explanation:

> Unicode decimal code &#105 is lower case "i", there are three lower case "i"s in the phrase, and since it's a word, you must be the dot above the i's, sometimes called "jot".

Comment: I learned something new! Still, it is not the intended answer.

Answer (score 4):

You could be

> [Robert Marchand](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Marchand_(cyclist))

Explanation:

> Robert Marchand set the Guinness World Record for the world’s oldest competitive cyclist (rider) at the age of 105.

You can find me 3 times in the phrase

> He was referenced three times in the given text: *I, I, & rider*

Hint

> The letter ‘i’, referred twice in the phrase, is used to brand most Apple products, e.g., *iPhone, iPod, and iOS*.

Comment: Very creative! But, not the intended answer.

Answer (score 3):

It is perhaps linked to

> *Vici* of Veni Vidi and Vici

the famous quote attributed to an emperor(on his conquering) and

> # one hundred five refer to repeated letters of i, c, v (though, a stretch and incompleteness here!)

Comment: Not the intended answer

Answer (score 2):

one possible answer, though not sure it qualifies as a word:

> the letter W or the letter L

Because

> there are three Ws and three Ls in the phrase

Comment: well, indeed this is not a word...

Answer (score 0):

The answer I deducted as per my understanding:

> **You** are found 3 times in the given phrase.

Description:

> 2 times when you reference yourself with "I" and 3rd time "me" in the word *aweso**me**ly*.

Not sure whether it qualifies the given hint about products.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Unfortunately, this answer doesn't satisfy the hint...

Comment: If you're going to count the "me" in awesomely, shouldn't you also count the "I" in win and rider?